# Free OS X utility to scrape web sites?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, utilities, websites, html

I want to scrape all the pages and subpages of a web site (by scrape, I mean save all the online content to local HTML files).

What is the best utility to crawl all the pages? Ideally, I would like to specify how many layers deep to scrape.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have two options:

You can use the `wget` command-line utility like so:

```
wget -rl 10
```

Replace the `10` with the number of levels you would like to recurse down into.

Or, you can use [SiteSucker](http://www.sitesucker.us/mac/mac.html). A GUI application that recursively downloads websites. You can also specify how far down to recurse with SiteSucker.

Comment: SiteSucker is great.

Answer (score 1):

#### [DeepVacuum](http://www.hexcat.com/deepvacuum/)

GUI for wget, $15.

[image]

#### [cocoawget](http://code.google.com/p/cocoawget/)

(free)

[image]

Comment: Deepvacuum makes me think of Dire Straits: "Money for nothing" :D